# How to exclude interaction term from glmulti?

Tags: r, glmulti

I am fitting the following:

```
offspring.survival_STAB <-glmulti(ST~ STAB + Age + BS+ BSP + Sex,
                                     data=ST, 
                                     exclude="BS:BSP",
                                     level=2,
                                     fitfunc=glm,
                                     crit="aicc",
                                     family = Gamma(link = "inverse"),
                                     method = "h")
```

The ain of this code is to get all the possible interactions excluding the interaction "BS:BSP".

However I get this error when I add exclude=c() in the formula:

```
Error in glmulti(ST ~ STAB + Age + BS + BSP + Sex, data = ST, exclude = "BS:BSP",  : 
  Improper call of glmulti.
```

Am I missing something about exclude=c()?
Is another way to specify interactions terms in 'glmulti'?

Comment: I think you want `ST~ STAB * Age * BS * BSP * Sex`. Otherwise, you are trying to exclude a specific interaction from models without interactions.

Comment: Thank Ronald but the interaction terms are already incorporated within the glmulti option (level 2 interaction)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Also, are you using glmulti version 1.0.8? Apparently, old versions didn't support formulas.

Comment: I use the 1.0.8 version, you can run the code provided above with the following data set:                           https://postbguacil-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/ronfl_post_bgu_ac_il/EZb46dS0MMBNk0mq3soZ7wwBS9QOpAezeTwE0_oNHFsuVA?e=JTATF6       

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`glmulti` does not take a formula as input. You specify the regression model by text arguments:

```
glmulti("ST", 
        c("STAB", "Age", "BS", "BSP", "Sex"),
        data=ST, 
        exclude="BS:BSP", etc.)
```

From the docs at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmulti/versions/0.5-1/topics/glmulti

From the comments it seems `glmulti` does not work one way or the other. Then there is doing it yourself!

This function takes a data frame and constructs an equation with all main effects and all pair-wise interactions, except those given as an argument. It assumes the left-hand side is in column 1 and that the remaining columns constitute the right-hand predictors. Accomodate the code as you wish:

```
make_eq = function(df, exclude) {
  Y = colnames(df)[1]
  X = colnames(df)[-1]
  terms = c(X, apply(combn(X, 2), 2, paste, collapse=":"))
  terms = setdiff(terms, exclude)
  terms = paste(terms, collapse=" + ")
  eq = paste0(Y, " ~ ", terms)
  eval(parse(text=eq))
}

obs = data.frame(
  Y = rnorm(10),
  A = rnorm(10),
  B = rnorm(10),
  C = rnorm(10),
  D = rnorm(10)
)

lm(make_eq(obs, c("A:C", "C:D")), data = obs)
```

Comment: `glmulti` is an S4 generic and there is a formula method. The documentation of the current version contains only examples using the formula method. Your link is for an outdated version.

Comment: Even so, maybe it works better with the old-fashioned, text-based inputs? Let's hear what works for Ron.

Comment: Well, with the text argument, it's run but ignores the exclude function.
The interaction is included in the model